# GA4 Refund data showing as "Unassigned" Traffic Acquisition report

Tags: google-analytics-4

We are using the Measurement protocol to push [refund](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/reference/events#refund)  data into GA4.  A refund will almost always be beyond 72 hours after purchase - so the [3 calendar day](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/reference?client_type=gtag#payload_post_body) limit I expect will mean that the purchase session we have will have expired.

How do we tie the refund attribution back to that of the associated order - so we can answer the question:

"Which acquisition channels are resulting in the most refunds"?

Happy for the answer to include - it's not possible within GA4 - or, you'd need to use BigQuery / LookerStudio to associate the separate events... but ideally - a proven, programmatic way to resolve the issue.

We've pushed the refunds into GA4 using the measurement protocol - hoping that when the GA4 report is rendered, the attribution of the end to end transaction would remain - but a new session is associated to "Unknown".

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp_micros key is optional, so in case it doesn't fit the 3 calendar day, you can remove it and the refund will be track when the hit is pushed.(better track it in a closer time than not track it, right?)

"How do we tie the refund attribution back to that of the associated order - so we can answer the question?"

According to the [data import](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6066862?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article%2Cdata-set-details) (I know that is not measurement protocol) it says:

> the Source and Medium dimensions of the refund data will reflect the
> campaign attribution and date used in the customer's last session.
> These may be different than the original transaction data.
>
> Example: you have a transaction attributed to google/cpc from customer
> A on date 1. That customer then has a later session on date 2,
> attributed to google/organic. If you refund the original transaction,
> the refund data will be attributed to the most recent Source/Medium
> which would be google/organic, and the date will be set to the day the
> refund is uploaded.